# Making an AJAX POST on websocket message is causing timeout exceptions

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, websocket

So I have a program that basically allows two users two chat back and forth and do other things via websocket with javascript and java server endpoints. When one of the users presses a button I have a listener that fires off a message to the other user which invokes a function. During this function I want to be able to call an AJAX POST with JQuery to update my database but this is causing a java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException. Any idea why this occurs? I imagine it has something to do with the fact that the websocket connection doesn't stay open long enough for the ajax call to go through.

So I've done the research and I've seen that websocket and AJAX are not exactly something that should be mixed (I think). However I can't seem to figure out an alternative even to update my database. There is a lot of code for this so I will try and only post the important parts.

Here is the part of the code for when the button is pressed (it is an agree button so both users must have pressed it hence the '**' and '--' characters).

```
        fAgree.addEventListener("click", function() {
        // selects this button
        if (aStr == "**" && (yStr == "**" || oStr == "**")) {
            if (fStr == "--") {
                fStr = "*-";

                //redirect to another page
            } else if (fStr == "-*") {
                fStr = "**";


            if(secondTransaction == false) {
                    var firstCoordUpload = document.getElementById("yourPos").innerHTML;
                    var secondCoordUpload = document.getElementById("othersPos").innerHTML;
                    var firstLatUpload = parseFloat(firstCoordUpload.split(",")[0]);
                    var firstLonUpload = parseFloat(firstCoordUpload.split(",")[1]);

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "../../309/T11/setSaleData/" + getURLParameter("saleID") + "/" + firstLatUpload + "/" + firstLonUpload + "/" + firstCoordUpload + "/" + secondCoordUpload + "/" + secondSeller,
                        type: "POST",
                        headers: {
                            "Authorization" : getCredentials(),
                        },
                        success: function (result) {
                            window.location.href = '../../frontEnd/profilePage/index.html?username='+ getUsername();
                            console.log(result);
                        },
                        error: function (dc, status, err) {
                            console.log(err);
                            console.log(status);
                        }
                    });                     

            }



            }
            agreeBut.socket.send("a,f");
            htmlChange(fStr, fStar);
        }
    });
```

Here is the part of the code that is called at the end of the code above (the agreeBut.socket.send()).

```
    agreeBut.socket.onmessage = function(message) {
    // check [0]: a for agree buttons,
    // m for map,
    // l of location buttons,
    // t for trade
    var mess = message.data.split(",");
    if (mess[0] == "a") {
        // second a shows the agree button was pressed, changes aStr
        // accordingly and displays
        if (mess[1] == "a") {
            if (aStr == "--") {
                aStr = "-*";
            } else if (aStr == "*-") {
                aStr = "**";
            }
            htmlChange(aStr, aStar);

            // shows the final agree button has been pressed, changes fStr
            // accordingly and displays
        } else if (mess[1] == "f") {
            if (fStr == "--") {
                fStr = "-*";
                //redirect
            } else if (fStr == "*-") {
                fStr = "**";

                alert("on this");
                if(secondTransaction == true) {

                        alert("doing it");
                        var firstCoordUpload = document.getElementById("yourPos").innerHTML;
                        var secondCoordUpload = document.getElementById("othersPos").innerHTML;
                        var firstLatUpload = parseFloat(firstCoordUpload.split(",")[0]);
                        var firstLonUpload = parseFloat(firstCoordUpload.split(",")[1]);

                        $.ajax({
                            url: "../../309/T11/setSaleData/" + getURLParameter("saleID") + "/" + firstLatUpload + "/" + firstLonUpload + "/" + firstCoordUpload + "/" + secondCoordUpload + "/" + secondSeller,
                            type: "POST",
                            headers: {
                                "Authorization" : getCredentials(),
                            },
                            success: function (result) {
                                console.log(result);
                                alert("Got it");
                                window.location.href = '../../frontEnd/profilePage/index.html?username='+ getUsername(); 
                            },
                            error: function (dc, status, err) {
                                console.log(err);
                                console.log(status);
                            }
                        });                     

                }



                //window.location.href = '../../frontEnd/profilePage/index.html?username='+ getUsername();
            }
            htmlChange(fStr, fStar);
        }

    }

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was getting this problem because of the timeout that was set on my java ServerEndpoint. In the class I used the setMaxIdleTimeout(0) function on the session variable to have no idle timeout. This seemed to solve my problem (however I feel like this is really just a workaround for poor websocket and ajax implementation on my end).